# How to show number after it's randomly generated?

Tags: java, jbutton

I want when a button is pressed to generate a random number and then display it in the frame. What should I do? Here is some code

```
JButton btnNewButton = new JButton("Money");
btnNewButton.setBounds(264, 5, 138, 78);
btnNewButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){


public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    Random myRandom = new Random();
    RandomNumber =myRandom.nextInt(100)+1;
    if (RandomNumber >= 50){
        System.out.println(RandomNumber);
        System.out.println("Yes");
    } else {
        System.out.println(RandomNumber);
        System.out.println("No!");
    }
```

Comment: And what does your code do, compared with what you want it to do?

Comment: Take a look at JTextField
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JTextField.html

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels I did not realize he was using an `ActionListener()`, my mistake. I typically use the `EventQueue.invokeLater()` method a lot and thought it may help him with his GUI code. -- removed.

Answer (score 1):

you should put some java title/textfield and change the text in it to the number you want

Answer (score 0):

OK, here is what you shoul do, but some advice first:

1) dont use fixed (null) layout

```
btnNewButton.setBounds(264, 5, 138, 78);
```

Use some [java layout](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/visual.html) instead, if you want to write Java GUI programs, you would have to learn it anyway.

2) Use proper variable naming `int randomNumber;`, not `int RandomNumber;`, everyone is needlessly confudes if you dont follow proper [coding convenctions](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/codeconv-138413.html)

3) And finally, how to display that number

As said, create some `Component` that can display text, like `JTextArea` or `JLabel` for example, add it to your gui the same way you add your button, then call

```
myJLabel.setText("new number"+randomNumber);
```

to change displayed text.

Comment: Hi again, since i don't have anything better to do at 1AM, here is an example: http://pastebin.com/GRHUWKie

Comment: Thanks for all kajacx! Really appreciate it =))